# How do you attach a service account to a gke deployment/servic like you can an ECS service?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, amazon-ecs, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-iam

Im coming from AWS not sure how to do this with gcp. Previously I asked a more general question about service accounts, this is specific to gke.

In AWS I can create an ECS service role. I attach policies to that role to give it the access it needs. Then I attach the role to an ECS service. So I can deploy multiple services to the same ECS cluster and give them different access with No static keys being used, no secrets being passed around.

How do I do this with gke? How do I attach a gcp iam service account to a gke deployment/service, etc? Can you used annotations in the deployment yaml to attach a service account?

I want to have multiple deployments and services on the same gke cluster using different service accounts implicitly (no keys being used)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Introduction:**

A Google Cloud Kubernetes Cluster consists of Compute Engine VM instances. When you create a cluster a default service account is attached to each VM instance. These credentials are stored in the instance metadata and can be accessed by using a default application `Client()` instantiation (Application Default Credentials) or by specifying the credential location.

ADC Credentials Search:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
```

OR only from metadata:

```
from google.auth import compute_engine
from google.cloud import storage
credentials = compute_engine.Credentials()
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)
```

**[Update]**

I do not want to promote poor security practices. The above techniques should be blocked on secure production Kubernetes clusters.

1. Use a minimally privileged service account for the Kubernetes cluster.
2. Disable legacy metadata server APIs and use metadata concealment.
3. Use a Pod Security Policy.
4. Use separate service accounts for node pools.
5. Restrict traffic between pods with a Network Policy.

**[End Update]**

**The Google Kubernetes Method:**

The recommended technique for Kubernetes is to create a separate service account for each application that runs in the cluster and reduce the scopes applied to the default service account. The roles assigned to each service account vary based upon the permissions that the applications require.

Service account credentials are downloaded as a Json file and then stored in Kubernetes as a `Secret`. You would then mount the volume with the secret (the credentials). The application running in the container will then need to load the credentials when creating Google Application Clients such as to access Cloud Storage.

This command will store the downloaded credentials file into a Kubernetes secret volume as the secret named `service-account-credentials`. The credentials file inside Kubernetes is named `key.json`. The credentials are loaded from the file that was downloaded from Google Cloud named `/secrets/credentials.json

```
kubectl create secret generic service-account-credentials --from-file=key.json=/secrets/credentials.json
```

In your deployment file add the following to mount the volume.

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: google-cloud-key
    secret:
      secretName: service-account-credentials
...
  containers:
    volumeMounts:
    - name: google-cloud-key
      mountPath: /var/secrets/google
```

Inside the container, the credentials are loaded from `/var/secrets/google/key.json`

Python Example:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('/var/secrets/google/key.json')
```

This document provides step-by-step details on service account credentials with Kubernetes.

[Authenticating to Cloud Platform with Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform)

Comment: Ok so there is no way to reference them implicitly. I have to generate a key for every service account, upload it as a k8s secret, mount it in a k8s secret volume, reference it explicitly in my application's code- correct?

Comment: Basically yes, that is the official way. Inside a container (or in a VM instance), you cannot reference credentials by name (AWS STS), you need the actual credentials file / OAuth Access Token. Google Kubernetes containers do not have separate independent metadata servers - meaning the metadata server is part of the VM instance and not isolated at the container level.

Comment: Outside the scope of this question,but do you know if eks on AWS supports service roles like ECS services? Or does eks work the same as gke here?

Comment: AWS is limited also but there are options. Look into Kube2IAM https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam . This could be an idea for Google K8s also. This would not be hard to implement.

Comment: Google is the father of Kubernetes, so AWS cannot deviate too far from the K8s core otherwise updates and third party support would be a problem. AWS does however tend to push the security features faster, which I like.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't think this is the best approach anymore, as it does not have Workload Identity mentioned anywhere. This documentation link here should help with this,https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#enable